# reduction steps for successor of 1 with Church numerals

Tags: lambda-calculus, church-encoding

I am trying to understand which are the right steps to perform the following reduction following the normal order reduction. I cannot understand which is the correct order in which I should perform the reduction, and why, in this expression:

```
(λn.λs.λz.n s (sz)) (λs.λz.s z)
```

could you please help me out?

Note: this reduction can also be seen as the function successor

```
(λn.λs.λz.n s (sz))
```

applied to the Church numeral 1

```
(λs.λz.s z)
```

knowing that the number zero is represented as:

```
(λs.λz.z)
```

Comment: normal order and left outermost if you can!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The normal, AKA leftmost-outermost, reduction order attempts to reduce the leftmost outermost subterms first.

Since you are looking for the outermost terms, you need to determine the main building blocks of your term, remembering that every term is a variable, an abstraction over a term or an application of terms:

```
(λn.λs.λz.n s (s z)) (λs.λz.s z)
---------LHS-------- ----RHS----
----------APPLICATION-----------
```

The left-hand side (`LHS`) of the main term is the leftmost outermost one, so it is the starting point of the reduction. Its outermost abstraction is `λn` and there is a bound variable `n` in that term, so it will be substituted with the right-hand term:

```
λn.λs.λz.n s (s z)
--       -
```

However, since both `LHS` and `RHS` contain `s` and `z` variables, you need to rename them in one of them first; I chose to rename the ones in `RHS`:

```
λs.λz.s z -> λa.λb.a b
```

Now you can drop the `λn` abstraction and substitute the `n` variable with `λa.λb.a b`:

```
λn.λs.λz.n s (s z) -> λs.λz.(λa.λb.a b) s (s z)
--       -                  -----n-----
```

It's time to look for the next reduction spot:

```
λs.λz.(λa.λb.a b) s (s z)
```

Since lambda calculus is left-associative, this is the same as:

```
λs.λz.(((λa.λb.a b) s) (s z))
```

The next leftmost outermost reducible term is `(λa.λb.a b) s` which reduces to `(λb.s b)`:

```
λs.λz.(((λa.λb.a b) s) (s z)) -> λs.λz.((λb.s b) (s z))
         --    -    -                       -
```

And the last reducible term is `(λb.s b) (s z)`, where `b` is substituted with `(s z)`:

```
λs.λz.((λb.s b) (s z)) -> λs.λz.(s (s z))
        --   -  -----              -----
```

Which leads to the final state in normal form:

```
λs.λz.s (s z)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! It's amazing! I have one more question: in this passage `λn.λs.λz.n s (s z) -> λs.λz.(λa.λb.a b) s (s z)` why did you obtain that result and not `λs.λz.λa.λb.a b s (s z)`. Is that the case that every time I substitute a λ-abstraction in another one I must include the parenthesis? @ljedrz

Comment: @elena It's because abstractions extend to the right as far as possible; if those parentheses were removed, it would change the whole structure of the term. You could write the initial `λs.λz.n s (s z)` as `λs.(λz.((n s) (s z)))` to see the subterm relations (the reach of abstractions and application order) in force - `λs.(λz.(((λa.λb.a b) s) (s z)))` preserves them, whereas `λs.(λz.(λa.(λb.(((a b) s) (s z)))))` changes them drastically.